# A paper: Accessible categories, saturation and categoricity

Tags: category-theory, cardinals, limits-colimits, locally-presentable-categories, accessible-categories

I've been reading a paper on **accessible categories, saturation and categoricity** by "Jiří Rosický" for quite some time,
but I still cannot understand one detail:
In the snippet below, in the Remark 1. why it is sufficient that the inclusion
$\mathbf {\text Pure_\lambda}\cal K\to\cal K $
preserves $\lambda^+$-presentable objects ? If someone is interested, I have a yet
one more (probably trivial problem) at the very end of the paper which I will
add here, in case this question is not going to be closed.

[image]

Definition of $\mathbf {\text Pure_\lambda}\cal K$.
[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Try to refrain from using pictures of text in posts because they are not friendly to users with disabilities and are not mobile friendly. It's better to insert the relevant passages into your post as text.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know this is not a good practice but I cannot draw diagrams here and the relevant parts of the texts are more easily referred to like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need that $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$ is $\lambda^+$-accessible, as is mentioned in that remark. Now let $f: K \to L$ be an arrow in $\mathcal{K}$ where $K$ is $\lambda^+$-presentable. Then, as an object in $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$, we have that $L$ is a $\lambda^+$-directed colimit of $\lambda^+$-presentable objects, so $L = \operatorname{colim}_{i \in I} X_i$ for some $\lambda^+$-directed diagram $(X_i)_{i \in I}$. Here we used that $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$ is $\lambda^+$-accessible. Note that $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$ is closed under $\lambda^+$-directed colimits in $\mathcal{K}$, this is always the case (see also point (1) in remark 1 of the paper you ask about). So we have that $L = \operatorname{colim}_{i \in I} X_i$ in $\mathcal{K}$ as well. Since $K$ is $\lambda^+$-presentable and $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is a $\lambda^+$-directed colimit, we have that $f: K \to L$ factorises as $K \xrightarrow{g} X_i \xrightarrow{h} L$ for some $i \in I$. The arrow $h$ comes from the colimiting cocone and is thus $\lambda$-pure. The object $X_i$ is $\lambda^+$-presentable in $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$, and by assumption the inclusion preserves $\lambda^+$-presentable objects, so $X_i$ is $\lambda^+$-presentable in $\mathcal{K}$. So we have fulfilled the definition of being weakly $\lambda$-stable, where $X_i$ plays the role of $K'$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot check as answered as I'm still going through your answer. I have added 3rd snippet in which in Proposition 5(b) I would like to understand how can all suitable $i_0$ and $i_1$ look like ? Can they be **any** elements in $I$ ? Or how is $\lambda^+$-directedness of $I$ used ? I'm definitely missing here something. What do I need to check before choosing appropriate $i_0$ and $i_1$ ?

Comment: Right, I have now understood your question but for a sketchy sentence: The arrow $h$ comes from the colimiting cocone and is thus $\lambda$-pure. Why is this true ? BTW, how can someone say about your answer that it is `obvious` as the author in Remark 1 ?

Comment: @user122424 As for the "sketchy sentence": this is because the colimiting cocone comes from $\mathbf{Pure}_\lambda \mathcal{K}$, so all arrows in there are $\lambda$-pure by definition. Unfortunately, "obvious" is overused in mathematics, it often means "working this out is straightforward, but also somewhat lengthy, so I will not do it here". Only the author knows why he decided to use that word here.

Comment: @user122424 Finally, as for your new question (about 5b): you should not ask multiple questions in one question. You should definitely not edit a question to add a new question. If you want to ask that question, you should open a new question.

Comment: Yes, I can ask a new question, it was just so related (in one paper) and so simple that I didn't want to spam this site with many related questions.

Comment: Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180165/directed-diagrams-in-accessible-categroies) for my new question.